# Derived Set of a given subset of Real Line.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A = \{a +\pi b : a , b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. What will be the derived set of it?

Comment: Derived set in what sense?

Comment: I think Varun wants the set of accumulation points of $A$.

Comment: Yes, Sir By Derived set, I mean the set of all limit points of the set $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is an additive subgroup of $\Bbb R$, which is not discrete since $\pi$ is irrational. A known result about additive sub-groups of $\Bbb R$ shows that $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ for the usual topology. Each point which is not in $A$ is a limit point.

For the points which are in $A$, we use [irrationality criteria](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~miw/articles/pdf/IMPA2010Cours2.pdf) (proposition 4 in the link).